# Create subdirectories within each existing directory by php

Tags: php, windows, command-line, directory

Need to create three (3) directories within ***each, already existing*** subdirectories (but not in any sub-subdirectories or deeper). The name of subdirectories varies and there is no consensus in the naming. PHP Windows Command Line.

**Start:**

```
C:/aaa         //this is the current working directory
C:/aaa/001     //subdirectory 001
C:/aaa/002
C:/aaa/ccc/xyz
C:/aaa/randomname
.
C:/aaa/z
```

**Result:**

```
C:/aaa
C:/aaa/001/dir1
          /dir2
          /dir3
C:/aaa/002/dir1
          /dir2
          /dir3
C:/aaa/ccc/dir1
          /dir2
          /dir3
C:/aaa/ccc/xyz
C:/aaa/randomname/dir1
                 /dir2
                 /dir3
.
C:/aaa/z/dir1
        /dir2
        /dir3
```

How to modify this php code so this takes place in each first level subdirectory?

```
mkdir("dir1", 0700);
mkdir("dir2", 0700);
mkdir("dir3", 0700);
```

Comment: this code needs more than a modification, it is missing all the code to figure out where to create the 3 directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify the arrays in which directories the folders should be created, and what folders

```
<?php
    $create_directoires = ["dir1", "dir2", "dir3"];
    $exclude_directories = [".", ".."];

    $dh = opendir(getcwd());

    while(($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
        if(is_dir($file) && !in_array($file, $exclude_directories)) {
            foreach($create_directoires as $create_directory) {
                if(!file_exists($file."/".$create_directory)) {
                    mkdir($file."/".$create_directory, 0700);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `$directories = ["001", "002", "003"];` the name of the subdirectories **varies**, so need something universal that works for **any** 1st level subdirectory

Comment: Well you have to tell me the way they are determined

Comment: the subdirectory names (`001, 002...999` in the above example) vary widely could be anything azAZ09 character, any length, etc.  there is no "consensus" in the naming of these subdirectories.

Comment: Either you can give me the nema of directory were directories 001, 002 etc are, or it has to be hardcoded

Comment: **"give me the nema of directory were directories 001, 002 etc are":** either use the `getcwd()` or similar php function to auto-identify the current working directory/path or - much less preferable - just use `c:\aaa` (i try to avoid to manually enter the path every new tree i execute the script).

Comment: works. tjhanks! the only small issue if it is easy to fix is **not** to create `dir1, dir2, dir3` in the current working directory (`c:\aaa\`) itself; only (as it does nicely) in the subdirectories.

Comment: It should be fine now

Comment: `Warning: mkdir(): File exists in..` error shows up.

Comment: Awesome! I updated the code just to check if folder doesn't exists before creating. Please mark the answer as accepted :)